# is there a Cydia tweak that will make Google Maps the default map app?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia, google-maps

The Cydia tweak Browser Changer lets you change the default browser on iOS. Is there a similar tweak for changing the default maps app? I'm specifically asking if there's a way to make the new Google Maps app come up when any type of navigation links are clicked.

Comment: There isn't one yet, but it should be coming soon. (especially because the API for the new maps has been released from Google).

Comment: @AndrewLarsson it has nothing to do with the API, but everything to do with URL schemes. You will need to convert the maps URL scheme to the google maps one, which may or may not be a big deal.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There's already a tweak now. I know that it can be done with URL schemes.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Cydia tweak available now called MapsOpener which should accomplish just that. http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/972329

Answer (score 2):

I think that BrowserChanger also supports maps now too.

Comment: If you have a link to this or can explain what version is needed, it will be helpful to others. Thanks, and Welcome to the site!